# in JS I Don't Know this Expression

Tags: javascript

```
function makeArmy() {

  let shooters = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    
    let shooter = function() {
      alert(i);
    };

    shooters.push(shooter);
  
  }
  
  return shooters;

}

let army = makeArmy();
```

`army[0]();` < -- - what is this ?

`army[5]();` < -- - what is this ?

Comment: `army` is an array of functions that are created in the `makeArmy` function ... so `army[0]()` calls the function in the first element of army - similarly `army[5]()` does the same with the sixth element of `army` ... the sixth element being the one after Leeloo

Comment: There is an array of functions. The code is simply calling a function that lives in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this back-to-front:

```
let army = makeArmy();
```

That calls a function...

```js
// ...and the function
function makeArmy() {

  // Creates an array
  let shooters = [];

  // It loops from 0 to 9 pushing a new function
  // into the array on each iteration
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    // Create the new function
    let shooter = function() {

      // I used console.log because it's much less hassle :)
      console.log(i);

    };

    // Add the function to the array
    shooters.push(shooter);
  
  }
  
  // And then you return the array of functions
  return shooters;

}

// An array of functions!
let army = makeArmy();

// Call the first function in the array
army[0]();

// Call the fourth function in the array
army[3]();
```